# Is there any way to make a collapsible SectionList in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a collapsible `SectionList` using react native. I'm able to do it by conditionally removing the data for the section that needs to be collapsed but it's not that scalable.

Comment: You can use this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-expandable-section-list

Comment: @KaranMehta Already looked into that library. It's not being maintained anymore, the last update was three years ago and it uses ```ListView``` which is not deprecated.

Comment: Try this : https://aboutreact.com/expandable-list-view/